# I want to enable captcha on guest checkout in Magento 2.3.1. I am using one step checkout

Tags: magento2.3, captcha

I know that it is a simple question. And you can follow this article to do that: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-enable-customer-login-register-captcha-magento-2.html

However, I believe that there is something wrong with my Magento installation. And it is not showing me **"Check out as guest"** option in the form section inside Captcha.

Can I enable the **"Check out as guest"** option manually using the command line or terminal or FTP?

Comment: Checkout as guest can be toggled in admin option. Have you checked this?

Comment: @DominicXigen I would like to know more about it. Please share with me a screenshot of the page.

Comment: @DominicXigen My requirement is that I want to have guest checkout and there should be captcha in it to avoid bots.

Answer (score 0):

To answer one of your questions. Guest checkout can be enabled/disabled

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/sales/checkout-guest.html

To disable guest checkout:

On the Admin sidebar, click Stores.

In the Settings section, choose Configuration.

In the Sales section in the left panel, choose Checkout.

Expand the Checkout Options section.

If necessary, clear the Use system value checkbox.

If the setting is for a specific store view, choose the store view where the configuration applies. When prompted, click OK to continue.

Set Allow Guest Checkout to “Yes/No”.

Click Save Config.

## Update

There is a discussion on this.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15164

I agree with one of the comments. In my mind the order flow doesn't work. The option shouldn't be on guest.  You have to use valid payment details to progress. Account could be created after.

Unless of course you have another scenario which requires you to have catcpha? Are you currently getting spam orders?

Comment: I have guest checkout enabled in my magento store. Now I want to show captcha during guest checkout  and this is the point where I am facing issues.

Comment: In guest checkout, I have COD (Cash on Delivery) as a payment method. So,  I am concerned that without captcha I might get spam orders.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution? How did you added recaptcha to guest checkout?